# Realm Swift : All records between specific time

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Considering that I have a object, something like this:

```
class SleepStatistics : Object {
  dynamic var onBedTimeStart:NSDate?;
  dynamic var onSleepTimeEnd:NSDate?;
}
```

I have several records per day basis, I want to filter only records between the time of 5:00 pm to 11:00 pm independent of day. Can any one guide me how to do that?

Comment: There are two dates in your objects, so please clarify what do you mean by a record being in a time period. Do you care about only the start or end date? Or does the start need to be after 5pm and the end before 11pm?

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention it, consider have several records between the time of 9:00 am to 11:59 pm for last one month, the average recorded time between start and end is 30-45 mins, I want to select records for last 5 day between the time of 5:00 pm (start) to 11:00 pm (end) only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `filter` of Realm Results. Like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "onBedTimeStart >= %@ AND onSleepTimeEnd <= %@", onBedDate as CVarArg, onSleepDate as CVarArg)

let result = realm.objects(YourObject.self).filter(predicate)
```

Comment: Already done this, if you check the question, i have asked what if i want to selected all the records regardless of date but only between the time of 5:00 PM and 11:00 PM

Comment: @BilalAshraf You can combine two conditions using `||` or `or` like: `realm.objects(SleepStatistics.self).filter("onBedTimeStart between %@ || onSleepTimeEnd between %@", [five, eleven], [five, eleven])`